# replay morsecode with flashlight?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, flashlight, morse-code

I'm trying to build a Morse-Code App which can replay Morse with the built in Flashlight. So I tried a few things, one of them slightly worked, but not how it should.

So essentially I type in a Message, let's say "hello". It translates to

```
.... . .-.. .-.. ---
```

Then I want to replay that by tapping a Button.
I've tried out different things. This was my first attempt:

```
 public void onPlayflash(View view) throws InterruptedException, CameraAccessException {
    if (result == null) {
        output.setText("ERROR");
    } else {
        currentposition = 0;
        if (currentposition < result.length()) {
            String c = String.valueOf(result.charAt(0));
            if (c.equals("-")) {
                //timeinmillis = 1000;
                //setTimer();
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], true);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], false);
            } else if (c.equals(".")) {
                //timeinmillis = 500;
                //setTimer();
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], true);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], false);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            currentposition += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work. It just said:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped (*always a random number over 1000 here*) frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Then I tried

```
public void onPlayflash(View view) throws InterruptedException, CameraAccessException {
    if (result == null) {
        output.setText("ERROR");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            String c = String.valueOf(result.charAt(i));
            if (c.equals("_")) {
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], true);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], false);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } else if (c.equals(".")) {
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], true);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], false);
                Thread.sleep(500);

            } else {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This kinda worked, but it still says

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped (*always a random number over 1000 here*) frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Actually the replay starts fine, but then it starts to struggle and skips parts of the iteration.

As you can see, I also experimented with android.os.CountDownTimer, but that didn't work out aswell. I only got one flash and then it stopped.

As you might see, I'm not that experienced yet '^^
Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to flash the screen black white.  You may be pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try again with CountDownTimer, but using recursion and passing a list of time to wait

```
private void test(List<Integer> resultTimeList, Integer count) {
    flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], true);
    new CountDownTimer(resultTimeList.get(count), 500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    flash.setTorchMode(flash.getCameraIdList()[0], false);
                    test(resultTimeList, count++);
                }
            }.start();

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I did it similarly. Instead of a list, I used a HashMap (worked better for me) and there were a few problems with final-declarations of parameters but in the end it worked out great! I not even freezes! Only a little problem: The app crashes after successful replay, but I think I'll be able to fix that. Damn that feels good!

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't even need an extra timer in the onFinish()-Method.